# ASP.NET MVC Render Partial on Dropdown List Value Change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to render a partial view dynamically when the user selects a value from the dropdown list. I've gotten quite far but can't figure out this last bit.

Here's the View/Quiz/AddQuestion.cshtml file

```
@model quizAppCodeFirst.ViewModels.QuestionTypes

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>

        Type @Html.DropDownList("QuestionTypes", ViewData["QuestionTypes"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })

        <div id="partialPlaceHolder"> </div>
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="Text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $("#QuestionTypes").change(function(){
     var stateId=$(this).val();
         $("#partialPlaceHolder").load("@Url.Action("MyAction", "Quiz")/MCQ");
   });
 });
</script>
```

In the QuizController.cs, this is the MyAction method that renders the partials

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string id)
{  
    Type t = Type.GetType("quizAppCodeFirst.Quiz" + id);
    return PartialView(viewName, t);
}
```

Till now, I've succeeded in rendering the partial view, but when I click the button inside the partial, it reloads the javascript / MyAction method.

Edit: To make it clear, I have main view which is View/Quiz/AddQuestions.cshtml and within it I am calling a partial view which is View/MCQ/AddMCQ.cshtml when the user selects MCQ from the dropdown list. The partial view (AddMCQ) loads perfectly fine and displays a form to add an MCQ with a Create button, but when I click the Create button, instead of calling the MCQController.cs/AddMCQ function, it calls the QuizController.cs/MyAction function. I can add the code for AddMCQ.cshtml but I feel like it's unnecessary since it works fine on its own.

Comment: You can not have javascript code in partial. And better to use `.on('click'..` than .change( because it not affect ajax reloaded code. I missing your question.

Comment: Where is the button code ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: @daremachine I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer. Let me know if I can add more details.

Comment: @Shyju I've edited the question with more details.

Comment: It sound like you have empty `href` attribute on Create button or no js listener is not handle that so fire browser standard page reload. Have you any js listener on click Create button? And stateId not used in context it should be "@Url.Action("MyAction", "Quiz")/MCQ/"+stateId; Or ..MCQ?id="+stateId ??

Comment: What is your expected behavior ? Where is the code to support your expected behavior ?

Comment: Can you show the Html generated after your partial view is loaded?